# Should not go back to login page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an issue with my navigation, after authentication is done I am able to navigate back to the login screen from the app navigation on back button press.Even I am using a switch navigator this is happening ,can you have a look and advise ?

.........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
.........................................................................................
..................................................................................................................................................................................
```

```
    const AuthNavigation = createStackNavigator({ 
      Login: { screen: Login, 
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#25D366"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff"  
        })},
      
        
        SignUp: { screen: SignUp, 
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#25D366"
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fff"            
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff"  
          }),
        }
    });
    const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator({ 
    Allo: { screen: BottomTabNavigator, 
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#25D366"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff"  
        }),
      
      },
      
     Profile: { screen: Profile, 
     navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
          headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: "#25D366"
          },
          headerTitleStyle: {
          color: "#fff"            
          },
          headerTintColor: "#fff"  
          }),
    },
    RendezVousForm: { screen: RendezVousForm, 
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#25D366"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff"  
        }),
    },
    RendezVousSetDate: { screen: RendezVousSetDate, 
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#25D366"
        },
        headerTitleStyle: {
        color: "#fff"            
        },
        headerTintColor: "#fff"  
        }),
      },
        RendezVousSetTime: { screen: RendezVousSetTime, 
          navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: "#25D366"
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
            color: "#fff"            
            },
            headerTintColor: "#fff"  
            }),
        
        
    },
    const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
          Home: { 
              screen: Home, 
              navigationOptions: {
                  tabBarLabel: 'Principal',
                  tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <MaterialIcons name="people-outline" color={color} size={size}/>
              }
          },
         
          TheProfile: { 
            screen: UserProfile, 
            navigationOptions: {
                tabBarLabel: 'Mes Rendez-Vous',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icon     name='video-camera'
              type='font-awesome'  size={24} />
            }
        },
      Paramètres: { 
        screen: MyDrawerNavigator, 
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icon name="settings" size={24} />
        }
    },
      Search: { 
        screen: SearchDoctor, 
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel: 'Search',
            tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Icon name="search" size={24} />
        }
    },
      
         
      }, 
      {
          initialRouteName: 'Home'
      }   
    )
    const MainStackContainer= createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
      {
      
       Splash:SplashScreen,
        AuthNavigation: AuthNavigation,
        CompleteProfile:FinishProfile,
       AppNavigation:AppNavigation
       
      },
      {initialRouteName: 'Splash',
      resetOnBlur:false,
      backBehavior:'history'
    }
      
    ));
```

Comment: You are using react-navigation 4 so you should use the switch navigation. For react-navigation 5, you can use the simple ternary operation to switch from unauth to auth state.

Comment: Thanks Rajendran,yes,I am using the switch navigator inside which I call the Aut navigator which include the Login component,have you seen?

Comment: I have an example boilerplate for react-navigation v5, but it wont work for v4, you can refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/auth-flow/

Comment: I will check it ,meanwhile if you can review my code and advise I would be glad